# Edit web module in intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I am going through the manual for our project and there is one step where we should "Add External Web Module".

There is a screenshot for Eclipse. Popup is called "Edit Web Module" and it has 2 rows for values:

Document base:

Path:

And one checkbox which says: "Auto reloading enabled".

But I am missing the very same screenshot or at least some steps for IntelliJ. I was able to find [coderanch comments](https://coderanch.com/t/682011/ide/Add-External-Web-Module) - it looks like it should be added inside tomcat but our manual says it is in IDE.

Also, Baeldung says https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-tomcat that it is a configuration for tomcat.

Question: How can I add an external web module in IntelliJ?

Comment: Please check related article: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/developing-web-applications.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[y.bedrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2960034/y-bedrov) Thanks for your answer! We can add a module in IntelliJ Idea exactly here:

- File / New / Module from Existing Sources
- Select module
- Open it